# Setting Pandas data into Qt's GUI (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have tried to use several QWidgets, but none gave me a working solution.

Here's an example that works when I run it:

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
import pandas as pd


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is the index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        data = pd.DataFrame([
          [1, 9, 2],
          [1, 0, -1],
          [3, 5, 2],
          [3, 3, 2],
          [5, 8, 9],
        ], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4', 'Row 5'])

        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

But, when I try to use the `TableModel` class for myself, it fails:

```
from PandasModelClass import TableModel
model = TableModel(dataFrame)
self.tableView.setModel(model)
```

It crashes during the `.setModel()` method. It says:

```
line 60, in showData
    self.tableView.setModel(model)
TypeError: setModel(self, QAbstractItemModel): argument 1 has unexpected type 'TableModel'
```

The variable `dataFrame` is fine, self.tableView is defined in a .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>593</width>
    <height>664</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="fileGroupBox">
      <property name="title">
       <string>File selection</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
       <item>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
         <item>
          <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="browseButton">
             <property name="text">
              <string>Browse directories</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
             <item>
              <widget class="QListWidget" name="fileListWidget"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QListWidget" name="tableListWidget"/>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </item>
           <item>
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>40</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
             <property name="text">
              <string>RadioButton</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_2">
             <property name="text">
              <string>RadioButton</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
         <item>
          <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView"/>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="plotButton">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Plot</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>593</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I don't see how is my implementation any different than the one from the example code, yet it crashes. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You cannot use PySide classes with PyQt (nor *vice versa*).

Comment: Okay, so specifically what should I change in my code?

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't provided a [mre].